# Control Loop Implementation - Kubernetes Alternatives

Tags: kubernetes, architecture, kubernetes-custom-resources

We are in the process of designing a cloud native application that needs a control loop to keep its objects (few thousands) in desired state.   Other than implementing the application as a set of Kubernetes CRDs,  we are wondering whether there are any other open source alternatives.  If you have developed your own custom implementation of control loop,  can you please let us know the reasons behind that decision (as opposed to using Kubernetes CRDs)?

Comment: Did you take a look https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cluster-api https://blog.container-solutions.com/kubernetes-operators-explained ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description seems to fit with the purpose of a CRD controller.

Check the [Kubebuilder](https://book.kubebuilder.io/introduction.html) framework, you can bootstrap a controller quickly and you will just need to implement the reconcile loop